# service broker ,same dialog is not used again even though it's status is connected

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

I am using SQL server 2012 at sender  and receiver's service broker

and i have the following contract and message on both

```
create MESSAGE TYPE [//Photo/Message] 
    VALIDATION = NONE


create CONTRACT [//photo/Contract]
    ([//Photo/Message]  SENT BY INITIATOR)
```

when i issue send message from sender  on a dialog for first time

```
DECLARE @dlgId UNIQUEIDENTIFIER, @AuditedData nvarchar(max)
select @AuditedData='some data which will not be validated'
        ;SEND ON CONVERSATION @dlgId    
        MESSAGE TYPE [//Photo/Message]   (@AuditedData)
```

the message arrives receiver queue

but when i use the same handler again ,the message is not sent from sender
as this handler becomes dead even though selecting from `sys.conversation_endpoints`  where conversation_handler = used conversation handler

shows that it is status is `CO` (connected) and it has a life time =`2086-01-14 11:49:47.677`

so what could be the reason that the handler is used once only at send but when reusing it again the message doesn't arrive receiver's queue

Comment: How are you using the same conversation handle? That is, from where did you get the handle for re-use?

Comment: i had put handlers ids in a table and when i want to use them again i make sure form sys.conversation_endpoints that their status is co(connected)

Answer (score 0):

when no acknowledgment is sent from receiver to sender ,conversation handler status will be connected ,but this handler is not going to be used again as it's disconnected,until an  acknowledgment  arrives from  receiver  to sender